# Why does my super sad face emoji change when I send it?

Tags: iphone, emoji

When the emoji pack was updated I could send the super sad emoji face

[image: sad emoji]

But now every time I try to send it, the emoji that shows up is ☹

Anyone knows why is this happening? My friends with iPhones have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug a while ago. The text version will only show up if you're using that emoji via the "frequently used" category. If you choose the one from the standard lists, it works. Suggest you update to iOS 9.3.